# How do I resize GNOME shell top bar

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-shell

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 and installed gnome-shell, but I found the top bar is larger than it normally is, how can I change its size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Hold both "`[Windows] key + [Alt]`"
2. "`Right-click`" the bar
3. Click "Properties".

In the "General Tab", simply resize the bar.

Comment: Dosen't work in modern gnome (3.X) from Ubuntu 20.04 etc.

Answer (score 7):

Find the file 
`/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css`

open it for editing by running the command

`sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css`

then in that file right in the begining you'll see

```
/* default text style */
stage {
    font-family: cantarell, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt; 
    color: white;
}
```

no change  `font-size: 11pt` to `font-size: 9pt`

and save the file, now you have changed the font size for the shell which will resize the top bar too, but now you need to restart the theme to load this file

so press alt + F2 and enter `r` and press enter

It shall work
I'm not using ubuntu but it works for me on fedora

Comment: Is there any way to make a local change instead of overwriting system files?

Comment: Its the shell theme, so it was supposed to be edited in shell level I guess, I haven't been following the updates in gnome shell though