# How to change gnome-shell titlebar height

Tags: gnome-shell

Is there a way to change the height of the titlebar in gnome-shell?

As it's currently too big for my taste, I'd like to make it a bit smaller.

Some themes get it right, but I don't know exactly where to look. I can only assume it may be css/js related.

My current `GNOME Shell` version is `3.16.4` and I am running Ubuntu.

This doesn't help: [How do I resize GNOME shell top bar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40415/how-do-i-resize-gnome-shell-top-bar). Wouldn't expect it either, but might have given me a direction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching "everywhere", i found an [archlinux forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1518845#p1518845) dating April 2015:

The following `css` needs to be placed in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

```
.header-bar.default-decoration {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.header-bar.default-decoration .button.titlebutton {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

I changed paddings to `1px` and now it's great!

Note: My hunch was right! It *is* css related